# AZURE B2C Custom Policy - Add page before the signin/up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need to configure custom policy in a was that user journey consists of additional steps:

- choose account type ( that is value of the enum:userType1,userType2)
- if userType1 than regular sign up ( local accoun or facebbok)
- if userType2 than creation of new account should require additional txt code input

So far i tried a lot, but docs are so confusing

```
 <ClaimType Id="invitecode">
                <DisplayName>invitecode</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
            </ClaimType>

            <ClaimType Id="accountType">
                <DisplayName>Acc type</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
                <Restriction>
                    <Enumeration Text="userType1" Value="userType1" />
                    <Enumeration Text="userType2" Value="userType2" />

                </Restriction>
            </ClaimType>
```

than

```
   <ContentDefinitions>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.pre.signup">
             // not sure about this, should this be custom cshtml stored in blob, and how it should look?
                <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>

                <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.7</DataUri>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="DisplayName">Pre-Signup Page</Item>
                </Metadata>
          
            </ContentDefinition>
```

```
 <ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>Pre-Signup Page</DisplayName>

            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-PreSignUp">
                    <DisplayName>Pre-Signup Page</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.pre.signup</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountType" />
                    
                    </InputClaims>
                  
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountType" />
                    </OutputClaims>

                  
                </TechnicalProfile>
               
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>
```

Can you please help me how to set up it? I use https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/SocialAndLocalAccounts as my base.

I tried to use code above